# what are some good scenarios in which to use reduce()?

Tags: javascript

What are some good scenarios in which to use reduce()? I've used map() and filter() quite a bit but I don't use reduce(), mainly b/c I'm not exactly sure what the  niche/benefits of the reduce() function are.

Comment: when you can do something in one step instead of multiple. Sometimes you need to map all the values, but you do not want X. You can do it with map and filter, or you can just use reduce.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - examples of reduce() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600900/javascript-examples-of-reduce-function) and [What does the Reduce() JavaScript function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392307) and [Is there any real benefit for using javascript Array reduce() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly, every scenario where you have to (ha!) *reduce* the initial array to **one single element**, while the other methods might also return an array whose length could be greater than 1